# Возможности Python для программ на контроллерах Atmel

Tags: python, микроконтроллеры

Кто-нибудь пробовал использовать Python для создания программ для микроконтроллеров Atmel?
Хотелось бы попробовать установить python в КПК.

Comment: есть вроде PyMite, который позволяет работать с atmel...
но не смог пока найти документацию и примеров... чтоб пропустить через руки и поэксперементировать))))

Answer (score 2):

Пробовать не пробовал, но вот ссылка - [Pyastra: python assembler translator](http://pyastra.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: благодарю, но там для PIC интересно с atmel...
найти бы для полного счастья примеры для начинающих))))

Comment: Ну в таком случае удачи в поисках ;)

Answer (score 1):

В микроконтроллерах atmel стандарт assemble и c. Для кпк смотрите в гугле, если ли сборки питона.